# How to get Agora io Screen sharing cancel event?

Tags: cancellation, screensharing, agora.io

I am using agora io for video calling and screen sharing. screen share is working fine. But problem is when I cancel the screen share then stream is not displaying. But join is still active. I need to catch the cancel event of screen sharing. I have read the document but there is no clue about cancel event. 
Would you please help to get the cancel event?
Advance thank you.

Answer (score 5):

```
    If you are using agora web sdk ng library then you can detect this by using track-ended event.
    
    We can create screen track using createScreenVideoTrack in this sdk.
step-1 call this method to create track
     async shareScreen() {
        const localScreenTrack = await AgoraRTC.createScreenVideoTrack();
        return localScreenTrack;
      }
 
step2- call event method after creating track.
 
    To add event on this track create different method to handle event
    shareScreenEvent(){
    const track = this.shareScreen()
    
     if (track) {
          track.on('track-ended', () => {
            console.log('track-ended');
    console.log('you can run your code here to stop screen')
          })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the Agora Web SDK NG, then you can use like this-

```
screen_rtc.screenTrack.close();
```

Here screen_rtc is my client object and you can also disable the screen client like below -

```
screen_rtc.client.leave();
```

My Full code for screen sharing is as follows -

```
<!-- Import Agora -->
     import AgoraRTC from "agora-rtc-sdk-ng";

<!-- Create client for screen -->
      screen_rtc: {
       client: null,
       screenTrack: null,
      },

<!-- Start Screen sharing -->
     screen_rtc.client = AgoraRTC.createClient({
       mode: "rtc",
       codec: "vp8",
     });

     await screen_rtc.client.join(
       <YOUR_APP_ID>,
       <YOUR_CHANNEL_NAME>,
       <YOUR_TOKEN>,
       null
    );

    screen_rtc.screenTrack = await AgoraRTC.createScreenVideoTrack();
    await screen_rtc.client.publish(screen_rtc.screenTrack);

<!-- Stop screen sharing -->
   screen_rtc.screenTrack.close();
   await screen_rtc.client.leave();
```

Answer (score 0):

Agora's Web SDK does not offer any methods to detect this, but since the Agora Web SDK is based on Web RTC you can leverage the `navigator` object and `catch` the error.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function success(stream) {
    /* media access has been granted */
}).catch(function(err) {
    //log to console first 
    console.log(err); /* handle the error */
    if (err.name == "NotFoundError" || err.name == "DevicesNotFoundError") {
        //required track is missing 
    } else if (err.name == "NotReadableError" || err.name == "TrackStartError") {
        //webcam or mic are already in use 
    } else if (err.name == "OverconstrainedError" || err.name == "ConstraintNotSatisfiedError") {
        //constraints can not be satisfied by avb. devices 
    } else if (err.name == "NotAllowedError" || err.name == "PermissionDeniedError") {
        //permission denied in browser 
    } else if (err.name == "TypeError" || err.name == "TypeError") {
        //empty constraints object 
    } else {
        //other errors 
        console.log("Error: " + err.name);
    }
});
```

Reference Link: https://blog.addpipe.com/common-getusermedia-errors/
Code Pen Demo: https://codepen.io/naicuoctavian/pen/wPeZWO

Answer (score 0):

This is an error and you should handle it. If a user cancel screen sharing, screen track will need to be stopped and leave. So, you can simply use try/catch.

```
try {
      await clientScreen.join(appId, channelName, rtcToken, screenShareUid);

      const screenTrack = await AgoraRTC.createScreenVideoTrack(
        {
          encoderConfig: interviewInfo.video_encoding[0] as VideoEncoderConfiguration,
        },
        'disable'
      );
      screenTrack.on('track-ended', () => {
        handleStopShareScreen();
      });

      if (screenTrack) {
        await clientScreen.publish(screenTrack);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      handleStopShareScreen();
    }
  };
```

and handleStopShareScreen function:

```
const handleStopShareScreen = async () => {
    if (screenShareTrack) {
      screenShareTrack.stop();
      screenShareTrack.close();
    }
    clientScreen.removeAllListeners();
    await clientScreen.leave();
  };
```